# Can't find module in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am facing this issue. when i am trying to run **app.js**

```
Error: Cannot find module './protocol/json'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\project\dev4\nodejs\node_modules\a
    ws-sdk\lib\core.js:31:11)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Any idea.?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share app.js file with us? Is /protocol/json.js is handwritten by you? If so, make sure that json.js file is located under protocol directory. protocol directory must be at the same level where your app.js is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node-webkit current directory would in fact be where index.html is located not in the current directory of the module in question. If you are not using node-webkit this is simply a failure to point to the correct location of the file.

*EDIT: If I am not mistaken, current directory may not be what you think depending on how the node.js script is executed and from where, but don't hold me on that please ;)*

In any case, and to avoid possible caveats with file paths I advise you to use [path module](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) that comes with node.js

Simply add this code inside a module you are requiring protocol/json from. (be mindful that if protocol directory is not the the current directory it will still fail to require it).

```
var path = require('path');
var json = require( path.resolve(__dirname, './protocol/json') );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this because I had forgotten to `npm install aws-sdk` in a project.  I had somehow gotten a `node_modules` directory in my home directory, which had an old version of `aws-sdk` that was being used instead.